# Is it possible to execute "create role" in createNativeQuery?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

I'd like to manage my roles from application. But when I use

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(String.format("create USER %1$s nologin;",tenantId)).getResultList();
```

The Query is beeing executed but an exception comes up.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Is there an appropriate way to execute queries like this from Java ?

Comment: I'd also like to know this.. I've tried researching but really, nothing comes up..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `executeUpdate` rather than `getResultList`.

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(String.format("create USER %1$s nologin;",tenantId)).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I already tried that - the exception diappears, but the query is still not executed.

Answer (score 0):

For those that use a shared EntityManager, you can use TransactionTemplate:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate tt;
```

Then:

```
tt.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
  @Override
  protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
    em.createNativeQuery(String.format("create USER %1$s nologin;",tenantId))
      .executeUpdate();
  }
});
```